# QLabel not showing up on QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I have 2 widgets which inherit from base class `QOpenGLWidget`.

It looks like this:

- one of type `class ColorWidget : public MainWidget`
- one of `class BWWidget : public MainWidget`
- with `class MainWidget : public QOpenGLWidget`

I am trying to draw `Rectangle` on the widgets using mouse events. I have a `Rectangle` class inherits from `QLabel`. I am able to draw rectangles on the widget using something like this

```
void MainWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_mousePressed = true;
        m_cursorPos = event->pos();

        m_selection.setTopLeft(m_cursorPos);

        event->accept();
        return;
    }

    event->ignore();
}

void MainWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    m_cursorPos = event->pos();

    if (m_mousePressed && event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        emit signalMouseMove(m_cursorPos, m_selection.topLeft());
    }

    update();
}

void MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot(const QPoint& currentPos, const QPoint& startingPos)
{
    m_selection.setTopLeft(startingPos);
    m_selection.setBottomRight(currentPos);

    m_item.reset(new Rectangle(this));
    m_item->show();
    m_item->render(m_selection);
}
```

For now, connections are as follows:

```
connect(widget1, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, widget1, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
connect(widget1, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, widget2, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
connect(widget2, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, widget1, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
connect(widget2, &MainWidget::SignalMouseMove, widget2, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
```

**Problem:**

As you can see both the widgets are connected to each other via signal/slots triggerring everytime event occurs on one widget. This leads to synchronized drawing but it creates `Rectangle`instance for each widget everytime `signalMouseMove`is emitted.

**What do i want**

- Everytime i draw on a widget using mouse it should show up on other widgets as well.
- Creating only single instance of `Rectangle` will help me synchronize `move` and `resizing` of the rectangle simultaneously on all widgets.

**What have i done:**

I tried to emit a signal on mouse release event passing the `Rectangle` to show it on other widgets.

```
void MainWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    m_mousePressed = false;
    emit draw(m_item);
} 

void MainWidget::showItem(const std::shared_ptr<Rectangle>& item)
{
    item->show();
}
```

And this is how connections are:

```
connect(widget1, &MainWidget::signalMouseMove, widget1, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
connect(widget1, &MainWidget::draw, widget2, &MainWidget::showItem);
connect(widget2, &MainWidget::signalMouseMove, widget2, &MainWidget::mouseMovedSlot);
connect(widget2, &MainWidget::draw, widget1, &MainWidget::showItem);
```

The slot `showItem` is called everytime i draw but it just doesn't show the drawn rectangle on other widget. Not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking, but maybe this will help: Qt Widget instances are unique, you can't have one QLabel instance somehow be two QLabels. Also, why do you create a new widget every time mouse is moved, instead of resizing the current one?

Comment: @hyde does it mean it is not possible to just to show the drawn rectangle by just passing it as a parameter? About creating new widget every time i move, i missed the boolean value, edited the question. Moreover, i would be drawing multiple rectangles on the widget.

Comment: You should probably create a MCVE... (see help section).

Comment: Ok got it. So i need to create separate instances of Rectangle for each widget. Need to figure out how do i link them for moving and resizing. MCVE, i'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Note: The `QOpenGLWidget` needs to be only the top-most widget in the stack. I.e. if you have overlapping widgets, make the top widget the gl widget, and then make all other widgets its (direct or indirect) children. E.g. you can have `QOpenGLWidget`, then `QMainWidget` as its child and `resizeEvent` reimplemented to have the `mainWidget`'s size follow that of the parent, then everything else done as usual as children of `mainWidget`. This ensures that the whole stack is rendered using OpenGL. You do not want multiple GL widgets as children of one parent!